# How to filter a lot of items in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I'm trying to filter an array in swift, it works great when I'm just trying to filter a few things but when I add to the list I get this error:

> Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider
>   breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Here is my code with the above error:

```
filteredArray = workArray.filter { $0.stateName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.firstName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.lastName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.countyName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.cityName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.communityName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.sectionName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.notes.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.email1.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.email2.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.email3.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.jobsiteID.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!)}
```

I have tried to split this process up like this

```
filteredArray = workArray.filter { $0.stateName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.firstName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.lastName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.countyName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.cityName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.communityName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.sectionName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.notes.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.email1.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!)}
```

and

```
filteredArray.appendContentsOf(workArray.filter { $0.email2.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.email3.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!) || $0.jobsiteID.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchString!)})
```

But I am getting duplicate objects in the array.

I could write something else that would then look for and delete duplicate objects but I would rather not. My question is how should I be filtering all this items.

Thank you for all the help

Comment: Does `workArray` contain duplicate objects?

Comment: Since a given object may match more than one condition you should put your final array into a set and then convert it back to an array in order to remove the duplicates

Comment: @ozgur  no, work array has only unique objects, no duplicates

Comment: @Paulw11   That is what I was thinking of doing but was trying to write less code and handle this problem in the filter process instead of handling the duplicates.   Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factor that behemoth of an expression out to a method on your datatype.

```
extension MyDataThingy {

    func anyFieldContains(searchTerm term: String) -> Bool {

        let fieldValues = [self.stateName, self.firstName, /* etc. */]
        for value in fieldValues {
            if value.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(term) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Then:

```
filteredArray = workArray.filter { $0.anyFieldContains(searchTerm: searchTerm) }
```

This will fix the timeout error from the type inference engine. It is also more readable, more understandable, and more maintainable.

Comment: I like this way, it does make it more readable, more understandable, and more maintainable.    Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

### Extended syntax

Try the extended syntax

```
workArray.filter { elm -> Bool in
    // put your conditions here    
}
```

this way you are helping the compiler to understand that the closure receive an element of the type of your array and returns a Bool value.